# How to get rid of this error while using google colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, tensor, tf.keras

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in tf__train_function(iterator)

ValueError: in user code:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1051, in train_function  *
    return step_function(self, iterator)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1040, in step_function  **
    outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1030, in run_step  **
    outputs = model.train_step(data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 889, in train_step
    y_pred = self(x, training=True)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/input_spec.py", line 228, in assert_input_compatibility
    raise ValueError(f'Input {input_index} of layer "{layer_name}" '

ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "sequential_30" (type Sequential).

Input 0 of layer "dense_30" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=1. Full shape received: (2,)

Call arguments received by layer "sequential_30" (type Sequential):
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(2,), dtype=float64)
  • training=True
  • mask=None
```

Answer (score 1):

try extending the dimension
model.fit(tf.expand_dims(X, axis=-1),y,epochs=10)

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you are using tf.keras.layers.Flatten() for the model definition.

The error is basically saying your model input does not match the training data set dimension.